# QDialog as top-level window doesn't work

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a main `QWindow` and a `QFrame` (`mainF`) on it, which contains some other gui elements. I maximize the `QFrame` as follows, if I click on a button on my `QWindow`:

```
  mainF->setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog);      
  mainF->setWindowState((mainF->windowState(), Qt::WindowFullScreen));   
  mainF->show();
```

To minimize the `QFrame` and place it in its previous position again, I have created a `QDialog` (`m_MinimizeFullscreenGui`) with a button on it, which appears immediately on the right top corner of my `QFrame` if I maximize it:

```
QRect windowRectangle= m_MinimizeFullscreenGui->geometry();   
WindowRectangle.moveTopRight(QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry().topRight());   
m_MinimizeFullscreenGui->setGeometry(windowRectangle);     
m_MinimizeFullscreenGui->setFixedSize(30, 30);   
m_MinimizeFullscreenGui->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);   
m_MinimizeFullscreenGui->setWindowState(m_MinimizeFullscreenGui->windowState()); 
m_MinimizeFullscreenGui->show();
```

The problem is: I want to have my small dialog window always on the top-level of my maximized `QFrame`. But if I click at somewhere on my `QFrame`, the dialog window goes in the background, so the `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` flag doesn't work.

Where can be my mistake?

Comment: Try to have a look to window modality http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#WindowModality-enum

Comment: The QDialog was nonmodal. Since a dialog is a top-level window as default, I have set my QFrame also as top-level window:

`mainF->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);` Now it works as expected. Thanks!